# C++ Random number from 1 to a very large number (e.g. 25 million)

Tags: c++, random, numbers, largenumber

How would you make a function that generates a random number from 1 to 25 million?

I've thought about using `rand()` but am I right in thinking that the maximum number, `RAND_MAX` is = 32000 (there about)?

Is there a way around this, a way that doesn't reduce the probability of picking very low numbers and doesn't increase the probability of picking high / medium numbers?

Edit: @Jamey D 's method worked perfectly independent of Qt.

Comment: You can use the utilities in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) to do this.

Comment: [```RAND_MAX```](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) is implementation dependent. It's guaranteed that this value is at least ```32767```.

Comment: @Nathan that should be an answer

Comment: @RussellGreene That would be a poor answer in my opinion.  As is this question is too broad

Comment: @Nathan I meant that but with an example. That is the "standard" way to do it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `qt` tag?

Comment: @skypjack OP seems to not know how to do it in QT. Fair question - *a priori* the standard solution might be in QT and other QT developers may need to know how to do this.

Comment: @djechlin he is using `rand` and not `qrand`. He says that he uses `QtCreator`, but it doesn't allow him to use the `qt` tag for such a question... I use the same ide to develop in almost each language at works!! My two cents: not about `Qt` at all.

Comment: @skypjack he says he's not sure if he should be using rand() but is not sure since it caps out ~32,000. Does qrand cap out around 32,000? If not then that would be an excellent answer to this question. OP probably didn't even know about qrand.

Comment: @djechlin `qrand` is all about defining a thread safe version of `rand`, unfortunately it suffers of the same limitation (that is `RAND_MAX`).

Comment: I included Qt as a tag because I had initially opened this question up to get c++ but also qt-unqiue methods of doing this, yes `qrand()` existed but I found out that it did have the same limitation as `rand()` which was also pointed out by @skypjack. I guess there is no other Qt-specific method of doing so and that was what I wanted to find out too.

Comment: If you had away to get three digit random numbers but needed a six-digit random, you'd just combine two of them. So something like: `((rand() * RAND_MAX) + rand())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could (should) use the new C++11 `std::uniform_real_distribution`

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(1, 25000000);

//generating a random integer:
double random = distribution(gen);
```

Comment: C++11 didn't age on this site, still new :)

Comment: @LogicStuff In comparison to the time C++ has been around I'd say it's still pretty new :P

Comment: C++11 adopted these particular libraries from boost so this is available in boost even if you are using an implementation.

Comment: @AlarmingMonkey Replace *could use* with *should use*. There's absolutely no excuse for not using it unless you're stuck on some prehistoric platform/toolset. You really should go to http://www.cppreference.com and read about what's available in the language that you purportedly use. You might be pleasantly surprised :)

Comment: Why real_distribution and not int_distribution?

Comment: @coyotte508 I could've sworn I made `random` a `double` .. oh well.

Comment: It would make more sense to use `uniform_int_distribution`. OP's problem was that they wanted something like `rand()` (which returns integers) but with a larger range.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ran3

http://www.codeforge.com/read/33054/ran3.cpp__html

You should be able to get what you want from it.

Ran3 is (atleast when I was still doing computational modelling) faster than rand() with a more uniform distribution, though that was several years ago. It returns a random integer value.

For example, getting the source code from the link above:

```
int main() {
   srand(time(null));

   int randomNumber = ran3(rand()) % 25000000;
   int nextRandomNumber = ran3(randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yeah, I was picking away at the edit while waiting on compiling code. Its up now. Likely would recommend the C++11 answer over the one I gave unless you need really good random numbers though.

Comment: Commonly, you cant use modulo operation to scale interval of random number generation. Resulting distribution becomes nonuniform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975/1628385 is what Semyon is referring to. There is an answer there on how to avoid Modulo Bias.